# ANTLR for C# product private methods for parsing rules

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to use ANTLR to create a parser for simple language using C# code generation.

I have successfully product MyLangLexer.cs and MyLangParser.cs with very very simple rule called 'rule'.

The problem is that the generated method rule() is private.

All I want is to use ANTLR to parse a string into AST.

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# v3 target produces private methods by default, in contrary to Java's target. Add the keyword `public` in front of those rules you want to be public:

```
grammar MyLang;

...

public rule // rule is now public
  :  other
  ;

other // other is private
  :  ...
  ;

...
```

Comment: thanks. there is very little docs about ANTLR so I read Java docs and fail to understand this detail.

Comment: @IdoRan, yeah, not all targets are equally well documented. You're welcome.